# How to send JSON object from mobile app to wordpress database?

Tags: android, wordpress, json-api

My wordpress site has registration form using contact form7 plugin which registers users. I want to use same registration using mobile app. I have designe one application through which i need to register. I am trying JSON api plugin. 
How can I send JSON object from mobile to wordpress to inser user data in database?

Please help.

Comment: Have you googled for solutions in google? What have you tried at the moment?

Comment: Just I recomend not to attack directly to the database, create a simple REST API and interact with it from the app. [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) is a good and easy library to implement REST in your app.

Comment: Thnx for rply.. I am trying JSON API plugin of wordpress to fetch JSON object in my wordpress code.  But what is URL which I  need to provide while sending request through app? How can I get JSON object in my wordpress code?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to create a webservice which handles incoming connection from your android app and wordpress site to your shared database.

If you want to use PHP, this is the sample PHP insert script using JSON

```
$json = '{"fielda":"apple","fieldb":"banana"},{"fielda":"orange","fieldb":"pear"}';

//decode to get as php variable
$arr = json_decode($json,true); 

mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName(field1,field2)
VALUES ('".$arr[0]['fielda']."','".$arr[0]['fieldb']."')")or die(mysql_error());
```

To Retrieve your data from HTTP post at php script:

You may want to try this:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Thnx Gene. I have tried same. But how can I retrieve this JSON object data in my php script?

Comment: Hi @chitram, you may want to use HTTP post to send the data over to your PHP script. take a look at this. http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139

Comment: I am trying JSON API. I have created my own controller. URL of api is :- "http://<mysite>/api/register/register_person/"

If I send simple parameter (e.g. name), my url is- "http://<mysite>/api/register/register_person?name=xyz".

Using above code I can insert xyz in my wpodpress db. 
But how it works for JSON object?

My JSON object is :-
{
"name":"xyz",
"contact":"11111111",
"email":"xyz@xyz.com",
}

Comment: http://<mysite>/api/register/register_person?name=xyz is a HTTP Get method. Unless you wish to expose all ur information on the address bar, http get is generally not advisable. For more info see: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: I am trying HTTP POST method. Is it mandatory to send data using JSON in android? If yes how can I get data fron JSON object in my php script?

Comment: Using json_decode. I'm pretty sure things u asked are all available in the web! Try googling! (: